# How to allow application to instal through Google play store on devices which support armeabi-v7a but limit for devices with other CPU architecture

Tags: android, android-ndk

Have read at many location that we can limit the application for installation by specifying APP_ABI in Application.mk place usually under /jni directory.

What I could not find out that if putting just Application.mk with line APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a in jni folder with nothing else in it and building the app using just ant also limit the application in the same way?

I am not sure how the filtering works in playstore but here is the situation.

1. Have an Android project with libs folder containing prebuilt armeabi-v7a libraries.
2. jni folder does not have anything. i.e. we don't use NDK for building any component of the app ourselves. Only the prebuilt libraries directly used in libs folder.
3. Application compilation is then compiled for final apk using normal "ant release" command.

And when this built app is uploaded to play store it is allowed to be installed on all devices but the ones that does not have support anything above armeabi-v5 the installation fails with Native ABI Mismatch error.

My question is even without any native components to be built with, can I still have Application.mk in jni folder, build with sdk and make play store filter this for devices that doesn't support v7 architecture?

If not what can I do to make this work?

Is there a way to check the filtering similar to playstore online before uploading to playstore?

If someone could explain how the filtering works and point me to some documentation it would be great.

Comment: Where are the prebuilt libraries? Are they under libs/armeabi or libs/armeabi-v7a ?

Comment: Strange. I thought that should be enough for the Play Store filter. You can try adding an Application.mk and Android.mk and use the PREBUILT mechanism of NDK.

Comment: That would add another call to ndk-build to build nothing. And also I don't see Application.mk getting bundled into the the APK so not sure how Google Playstore would find which ABI this APK supports.